# Get a list of connected users

Tags: mongodb

Using the shell, can I get a list of users connected?  I can get the number of connections using db.serverStatus().connections and I can get the host connection information using

```
 db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(d){if (d.client)printjson(d.client)})
```

However, I want to know if I can get the user that connected from the host as well?

Answer (score 1):

**MongoDB 3.4.2**

I've been hoping to find a command like MySQL's `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as well, to easily get just such information. Disappointingly, it looks like there is no function that will show you which users are currently connected, or, for a given past or present connection, which user initiated it. But with profiling enabled we can approximate some of that functionality by looking into the recent past.

In my case profiling is set to 2 globally (visible with `db.getProfilingLevel()`), so at some point in the life of each database a collection appears in it called "system.profile", which is a capped collection - i.e. records are only retained until the collection is full and then replaced on a first-in-first-out basis (see disclaimer below). This collection can be queried as usual and keeps a timestamp (`ts`) associated with each operation.

```
var all_dbs = db.runCommand({listDatabases:1});
var now = new Date();

// Modify the number of seconds for a larger or smaller time window
var just_now = new Date(now.getTime() - 1000); 

all_dbs.databases.forEach(
    function(current_db) {

        // The condition there is to exclude internal commands executed by the user "__system"
        // To exclude this command itself, add  the condition "ns:{$not:/profile$/}"
        all_operations = db.getSiblingDB(current_db.name).system.profile.find({user:{$not:/^__/}});
        all_operations.forEach(
            function(operation) {
                if (operation.ts > just_now) {

                    // Remove the .substring(0,200) to unlimit output length 
                    print(JSON.stringify(operation.ts),
                          JSON.stringify(operation.user),
                          JSON.stringify(operation.query||operation.command||operation.updateobj).substring(0,200));
}})});
```

Output looks like this:

```
"1998-04-01T22:14:56.431Z" "<user>@admin" "<database>.<collection>" "{ insert: \"<collection>\", ordered: false, documents: ...
```

**Disclaimers**:

1. I am sure this is not the best way to do this, and MongoDB is practically my only use for Javascript so I may have done things here that make real Javascript people clench their teeth. Teeth clenchers-- feel free to edit in better practices.
2. For instances with a lot of activity this does not work and instead this error is thrown. I guess `find()` returns results from system.profile and those results no longer exist by the time it finishes executing so it breaks. `Executor error during find command: CappedPositionLost: CollectionScan died due to position in capped collection being deleted. Last seen record id: RecordId(19041841)`